# React: Animating a Component onto the webpage - Expanding one component while shrinking another

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, web-frontend

So I've spent quite a while looking into this and haven't found a specific example for what it is I'm trying to do. Currently I'm working on the landing page for a project, and so far it consists of two main components. `Aside` and `FormSide`. At the moment the encapsulating div for each component has the css set such that the width is 50%, i.e they are split vertically on the webpage as so:
[image: Current homepage iteration]
**What I'm trying to do:**
However what I really want is the grey half to be the entirety of the page, and upon clicking a specific element on the page, the blue login region extends out from the right hand-side, with the grey div shrinking to finish at the image above.

I've looked into react-animations [here](http://react-animations.herokuapp.com/), but I'm lost in regards to how to use this properly, as this involves essentially resizing, shrinking one component while animating in another, all in sync.

This would be easy enough to do in javascript with simple function call on click and altering some css, however I'm trying to get to grips with React so would love to know how to do it using solely this approach.

I know I will need some element `clickMe` on the webpage, which upon being clicked calls a function. But really how this function then alters the css of both the divs to expand one and shrink the other, or calls an animation on both of them is lost on me. I feel this is really basic stuff, but I'm extremely new to React so just cant get my head round doing this currently.

I've included some basic code underneath to give the structure of the webpage:

**JSX:**

**App.js**:

```
function App() {
    const name = 'test';

    return(
        <div className="App">
            <Landing_Aside />
            <Landing_FormSide />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Landing Aside:**

```
class Landing_Aside extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
        <div className="App__Aside">
            ... All html for title and subtitle (grey region) ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

**Landing_FormSide**

```
class Landing_FormSide extends React.Component{
render(){
    return(
        <div className="App__Form">
            ... All html seen to produce blue region...
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

**CSS:**

**App_Aside**

```
.App__Aside {
width: 50%;
...irrelevant css...
}
```

**App_Form:**

```
.App__Form {
width: 50%;
..irrelevant css...
}
```

**EDIT**
I've just stumbled across a package known as '[react-expand-animated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-expand-animated)', which seems to be doing *exactly* what I want, however I'm still struggling to find a way to use this. In the example in the link provided, the component which is clicked is expanded. Ideally, the `ClickMe` component would be a separate entity which then expands and collapses the `Landing_FormSide` component.

Comment: Please see [how to minimize your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Rojo I've practically removed everything I possibly can? The code is essentially just the names of the divs and classes involved?